# can i kill specific thred of a process at command line in linux using any command?

Tags: linux

i want to kill specific thread of a process at command line..is there some command to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

there is an api for this, on linux:

> int tkill(int tid, int sig);

refers to man page tkill(2)

Comment: +1 even though its a function and not a command. But it is advisable to use `tgkill` instead if `tkill` as specified in the `man` page

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this. Most programs are not designed to handle one of their threads being shut down without their knowledge. The program might have passed important data off to that thread, or might be waiting for it to finish.

If it is truly a concern, you can attempt to find a single-threaded or multi-process version of the program. For example, Apache has both a prefork (non-threaded) and worker (threaded) version.

Comment: But, if you want to kill a running program then you can use the 'kill pid' command.